# Shiny Sliders Dependent on Single Checkbox

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have a Shiny App and I am trying to have two sliders appear only if the checkBox is selected. Below is the code I am trying to get to work and am not seeing the UI.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  checkboxInput("box_checked", "box_checked", value = FALSE),
  uiOutput("test")
)

# Define server logic 
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$test = renderUI({
    if (input$box_checked = 0){
      return(NULL)
    }


    if(input$box_checked = 1){
      sliderInput("sliderOne", "Choose your value", min=0, max=100, value=50)
      sliderInput("sliderTwo", "Choose your other value", min=0, max=50, value=25)
    }

  })


}
# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(checkboxInput("box_checked", "box_checked", value = FALSE),
                uiOutput("test"))

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$test = renderUI({
    if (input$box_checked == 0) {
      return(NULL)
    }


    if (input$box_checked == 1) {
      list(
        sliderInput(
          "sliderOne",
          "Choose your value",
          min = 0,
          max = 100,
          value = 50
        ),
        sliderInput(
          "sliderTwo",
          "Choose your other value",
          min = 0,
          max = 50,
          value = 25
        )
      )
    }

  })


}
# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

1. I fixed `if` statement, as you used `input$box_checked = 1` instead of `input$box_checked == 1`.
2. You should use `list()` to produce multiple UI elements inside `renderUI`.

Comment: Btw you can also save some typing excluding the whole first `if` statement - there is really no need to return `NULL` if you want nothing to see.   
And also you can just use `if (input$box_checked)` since `input$box_checked` is logical by it self.
I can't decide is this real improvement or just making your code a bit more confusing but anyway it`s possible.