# Slider input determines how many additional sliders pop up in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Previous questions have addressed how to use check boxes to determine which sliders pop up ([Shiny Sliders Dependent on Single Checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50727061/9096420) and [R shiny Multiple slider dynamic inputs based on checkbox inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74163023/9096420)), however I'd like to do this with another slider (not a checkbox).

Something like the following (adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/74163251/9096420):

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput("choosemedia", "Choose number of sliders",
                     min=0,max=3,value=1),
  textOutput("myText"),
  conditionalPanel(
    condition = "input.choosemedia.includes('1')",
    sliderInput("sliderOne", "Choose value no 1",
                min = 0, max = 100, value = 50)
  ),
  conditionalPanel(
    condition = "input.choosemedia.includes('2')",
            sliderInput("sliderOne", "Choose value no 1",
                min = 0, max = 100, value = 50),
            sliderInput("sliderTwo", "Choose value no 2",
                min = 0, max = 100, value = 50)
  ),
  conditionalPanel(
    condition = "input.choosemedia.includes('3') ",
            sliderInput("sliderOne", "Choose value no 1",
                min = 0, max = 100, value = 50),
            sliderInput("sliderTwo", "Choose value no 2",
                min = 0, max = 100, value = 50),
            sliderInput("sliderThree", "Choose value no 3",
                min = 0, max = 50, value = 25)
  )
)


# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$myText <- renderText({
    input$choosemedia
  })
}
# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Yet, all the sliders pop up, regardless of the initial selection:

[image]

Using `if()` statements (adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/50727185/9096420):

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput("choosemedia", "Choose number of sliders",
                     min=0,max=3,value=1)
)


# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$myText <- renderText({
    input$choosemedia
    
    if(input$choosemedia == 1){
    list(
      sliderInput("sliderOne", "Choose value no 1",
                  min = 0, max = 100, value = 50)
    )
    }
    
    if(input$choosemedia == 2){
    list(
      sliderInput("sliderOne", "Choose value no 1",
                  min = 0, max = 100, value = 50),
      sliderInput("sliderTwo", "Choose value no 2",
                  min = 0, max = 100, value = 50)
    )
    }
    
    if(input$choosemedia == 3){
    list(
      sliderInput("sliderOne", "Choose value no 1",
                  min = 0, max = 100, value = 50),
      sliderInput("sliderTwo", "Choose value no 2",
                  min = 0, max = 100, value = 50),
      sliderInput("sliderThree", "Choose value no 3",
                  min = 0, max = 100, value = 50)
    )
    }


  })
}
# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The sliders don't show up at all:

[image]

Any idea if this is possible and what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `input.choosemedia` is a number (which has no `.includes` method) whereas you assume it is an array or a string (which has an `.includes` method). Hence, changing your condition you could achieve your result with less duplicated code like so:

```r
library(shiny)
#> Warning: package 'shiny' was built under R version 4.3.1

ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput("choosemedia", "Choose number of sliders",
    min = 0, max = 3, value = 1
  ),
  textOutput("myText"),
  conditionalPanel(
    condition = "input.choosemedia > 0",
    sliderInput("sliderOne", "Choose value no 1",
      min = 0, max = 100, value = 50
    )
  ),
  conditionalPanel(
    condition = "input.choosemedia > 1",
    sliderInput("sliderTwo", "Choose value no 2",
      min = 0, max = 100, value = 50
    )
  ),
  conditionalPanel(
    condition = "input.choosemedia > 2",
    sliderInput("sliderThree", "Choose value no 3",
      min = 0, max = 50, value = 25
    )
  )
)


# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$myText <- renderText({
    input$choosemedia
  })
}
# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
#> 
#> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:5150
```

[image]

A second option would be to use `renderUI` and `uiOutput` like so:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput("choosemedia", "Choose number of sliders",
    min = 0, max = 3, value = 1
  ),
  textOutput("myText"),
  uiOutput("sliders")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$myText <- renderText({
    input$choosemedia
  })

  output$sliders <- renderUI({
    lapply(seq_len(input$choosemedia), \(x) {
      if (x <= 2) {
        max <- 100
        value <- 50
      } else {
        max <- 50
        value <- 25
      }
      sliderInput(
        paste0("slider", x),
        paste0("Choose value no ", x),
        min = 0, max = max, value = value
      )
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
#> 
#> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:5743
```

[image]